# Weird behavior of mysqli->query for multiple DELETE

Tags: php, mysqli

I am running following query by using `mysqli->query` but despite of showing affected rows removing correct records,MYSQL is not removing the records. The same query runs perfect on command line.

```
DELETE m,s FROM t1 m
LEFT JOIN t2 s ON t1.sbid = t2.sb_message_id
WHERE m.sbuid = 11
```

`mysqli->affected_rows` gives correct count but its weird that records are not being removed.

OK just checked that even a single Delete query is not being executed. Let me also clear that I am deleting within a loop.

Comment: What is the number of affected rows? 2?

Comment: Ok it seems that autocommit is the main culprit. By default it was true. I set it to false then after loop block I manually comitted the records.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this SQL it is very clear at it is illformed. The format expected for delete statement is:

```
Delete from TableName where condition
```

So there is no field name between Delete and from allowed. The technical reason is [delete](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) deletes rows not fields.

In case you want to "delete" fields, ie, change value to null then you need to [update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) the record and set values for the fields to null.